# Is it possible to apply position: sticky to <thead> or <tr> element?

Tags: css, css-position, html-table, sticky

Is it possible to apply `position: sticky` to `<thead>` or first `<tr>` tag to make table header stuck at the top of viewport while scrolling the table body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to apply `position: sticky` to `thead` or `tr` elements. The [`position` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css3-positioning-20150203/#position-property) can be applied to

> all elements except table-column-group and table-column

But no, it won't behave like you want:

> The effect of [`position: sticky`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css3-positioning-20150203/#valdef-position-positionfake-maybe-placeholdersticky-fake-maybe-placeholder) on table elements is the same as for
>   [`position: relative`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css3-positioning-20150203/#valdef-position-positionfake-maybe-placeholderrelative-fake-maybe-placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

**No**. The [specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-position/) abstract explicitly states:

> Other kinds of layout, such as *tables*, "floating" boxes, ruby annotations, grid layouts, columns and basic handling of normal "flow" content, are described in other modules.

Comment: Note this means that [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/) doesn't standardize tabular layouts. But it standardizes the positioning and stacking of elements, including tabular ones.